# fread skip bytes at start and at end c/c++

Tags: c, fread

I'm trying to read binary data from file using fread in c and i want to skip first 12 Bytes and last 16 bytes of a file. I've figured out how to skip first 12 bytes bytes.

```
fread(iv, 1, 12, file);

while (1){  
        bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file);

        //How to skip last 16 byets ???
        if (bytesRead <= 0) {


            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: No you haven't. Please read about fseek. And ensure that your fopen uses binary mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple choice:

- You can read all and get a sub buffer of your buffer.
- You can see the size of the file using `stat()` and read `size - 12 - 16`

Comment: i can't read whole file at time. I've to read file in chucks and perform operation on those bytes.

Comment: `sizeReadedAllTime - 12 - 16` is your end condition of your while

Comment: I've to read 1024 bytes at a time. Above condition not gonna always skip 16 bytes

Comment: Last time you read of `size_left - 16` I don't understand your problem

Comment: Now I got it.Thank you